# How to override BasicErrorController

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have the following issue... I need to add some data to the model when the error has happened. For instance, I need to add the menu items to the error page and I tried to do it like this:

```
public CustomErrorController extends BasicErrorController {
    @Override
    public ModelAndView errorHtml(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        final ModelAndView modelAndView = super.errorHtml(request, response);
        modelAndView.getModel().put("menuItems", List.of("item1", item2));
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

and this code doesn't work. I need the logic of BasicErrorController, and I just want to add some data to the model.
How can I do it?

Comment: Use a `HandlerInterceptor` to add the items.